# Problems in R update

Tags: r, rstudio

Hi I would like to update my R version but an errors occurs. Could I ask for help regarding to this, please? Thank you in advance! Here is the error.

> install.packages("installr")
> Installing package into ‘/home/ss2826/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/installr_0.23.4.tar.gz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 158533 bytes (154 KB)
> ==================================================
> downloaded 154 KB

- installing *source* package ‘installr’ ...
  ** package ‘installr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  ** help
  *** installing help indices
  ** building package indices
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
  ** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
- DONE (installr)

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmpyfEzg6/downloaded_packages’

> library(installr)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘installr’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> unable to load shared object '/usr/local/Cluster-Apps/R/R.4.0.3/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
> /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/Cluster-Apps/R/R.4.0.3/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so)

I am using a HPC, so have no clue if there is any other ways I could update it.

Comment: libstdc is a part of `gcc`. Chances are, you need to install `gcc`

Comment: I would suggest not using `installr`, that's not an official R package. How did you install R the first time on your machine? What OS version are you running? You should ask your cluster administrator how you should proceed.

Comment: Many thanks! I might going to as the administrator about the updating. Thanks for all the suggestions!